# Can I create a Postgres index that is bigger than RAM?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, ram

As the title says: is it possible to create, and use, a Postgres index that is larger, when created, than the value of RAM?

Clearly it's not *ideal* to do this, because even if it's possible it will be much faster if the index can be in RAM: but I'm interested in whether it's possible at all.

I am asking this question because I'd like a rough idea of the size of server I need for a particular project.

I've looked through the [Postgres docs on creating an index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html), but I don't see the answer there. I suspect this is too basic a question even to be covered in the docs, and apologies if it's a stupid question :-(

Comment: Most DBMS can create indexes that are bigger than the amount of RAM you have if the index will ultimately be stored on disk.  If you have an in-memory database, you can't do that (usually).  Everywhere else, you can.  So, you should be fine.  (Similar thoughts apply to tables, too; Postgres doesn't limit your tables to the size of memory either.)

Comment: BTW: size of the server: I have a ~10 GB ( >3M rows in the "main" table) Postgres DB running on a Raspberry Pi Mk1, which only has 512MB of RAM, of which only ~half is usable. It would not even *work* without indexes ...

Comment: I don't think anyone ever thought to say that indexes could be bigger than RAM, it's just kind of assumed. Much like it never says that tables can be bigger than RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Ram is not a limit. Disk will be used to sort data and index building.